# How to read parts of an RTF file and keep formatting

Tags: c#, wpf, rtf

I was asked to create a control that reads in an rtf file and display the file in parts. The problem I am running into is that the font styling seems to be stored at a higher level than the snippets that I am pulling out. Is there a way to read snippets from one file and keep the formatting? I am using a RichTextbox in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfect solution, but it works for my specific scenario. I am posting it in case it helps others later, but I am still looking for a better solution. For the below to work, it has two pre-requisites:

- My delimiter has to be at the beginning and end of the text
- My delimiter has to be a different font or style so that it has its own distinct markup from any surrounding text

Code:

```
private static IEnumerable<String> GetListFromDelimitedText(String text)
{
  var textSplit = text.Split(new[] { "~~~~~~~~" }, StringSplitOptions.None);

  var header = GetHeaderOfRtf(textSplit);
  var footer = GetFooterOfRtf(textSplit);
  var listWithoutHeaderAndFooter =
    textSplit.Where((text, index) => index > 0 && index < textSplit.Length - 1);
  return GetSnippetsWithHeaderAndFooter(listWithoutHeaderAndFooter, header, footer);
}

private static IEnumerable<String> GetSnippetsWithHeaderAndFooter(IEnumerable<String> snippetList, String header, String footer)
{
  return snippetList.Select(text =>
    {
      var textWithoutLeadingBracket = text.Substring(text.IndexOf('}') + 1);
      var cleanedText = textWithoutLeadingBracket.Substring(0, textWithoutLeadingBracket.LastIndexOf('{'));
      return header + cleanedText + footer;
    }
  );
}

private static string GetFooterOfRtf(IEnumerable<String> textSplit)
{
  var lastSplit = textSplit.Last();
  return lastSplit.Substring(lastSplit.IndexOf('}') + 1);
}

private static string GetHeaderOfRtf(IEnumerable<String> textSplit)
{
  var firstSplit = textSplit.First();
  return firstSplit.Substring(0, firstSplit.LastIndexOf('{'));
}
```